# Design-pattern/solution for logically similar functions without code dupplication

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am looking for an elegant solution for the following (generic) problem. I want to implement several protocols to access files. Let's say ftp and tftp. More may be added in the future. Right now i'm doing:

```
get_file(filename):
  # some generic code for opening the file etc.
  if mode == 'ftp':
    get_file_ftp(filename)
  else:
    get_file_tftp(filename)
  # some generic code for closing the file etc.

get_file_ftp(filename):
  # ftp-specific code

get_file_tftp(filename):
  # tftp-specific code
```

Same for `put_file()`, `ls()` and a dozen more funtions. As code grows, this is starting to get ugly. So my question is: Is there a more clever way to get the job done? Is thera a design pattern that makes sense for this use case? If so, how would i accomplish this in Python?

Comment: Well, it's the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You could pass the function, e.g. `get_file_ftp`, instead of the `mode`.

Comment: Alternatively, it's the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). A common way of doing this in Python, particularly with resources, is to use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html).

Answer (score 1):

Two patterns which you can refactor towards are Strategy and Decorator.

The [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is often implemented in Python using context managers. There is a library to make them easier to implement, [**`contextlib`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_file(filename):
    # some generic code for opening the file etc.
    yield
    # some generic code for closing the file etc.
```

The `yield` statement enables you to inject whatever you want while you're in the `with` block:

```
with get_file(filename) as resource:
     get_file_ftp(resource)
```

or:

```
with get_file(filename) as resource:
     get_file_tftp(resource)
```

The `with` block will ensure the statements after the `yield` are executed, even in the presence of exceptions.

Another way of implementing decorators is with Python's [decorator syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). I suggested a context manager because I thought you wanted before and after statements whatever happened in between. Python's decorator syntax would make you have to implement the exception handling yourself. The decorator modifies the function

```
def get_file(function):
    def generic_code(filename):
        ... # some generic code for opening the file etc.
        function(filename)
        ... # some generic code for closing the file etc.
    return generic_code
```

Usage:

```
@get_file
def get_file_ftp(filename):
    ... # ftp-specific code
```

Alternatively, with the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), you'd pass the strategy for handling different file sources into the `get_file` function:

```
def get_file(filename, file_strategy):
    # some generic code for opening the file etc.
    file_strategy(filename)
    # some generic code for closing the file etc.
```

Then use it like:

```
get_file(filename, get_file_ftp)
```

or:

```
get_file(filename, get_file_tftp)
```